# Use url drop of WebBrowser control in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, drag-and-drop, webbrowser-control

I would like to use the drop functionality of the `WebBrowser` control in C#. Unfortunately it doesn't work although I set the `AllowWebBrowserDrop` property to true.

For testing I wrote this little programm with just a textbox and a webbrowser control:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    webBrowser1.AllowWebBrowserDrop = true;
    textBox1.Text = "http://www.google.com";
}

private void textBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        DoDragDrop(textBox1.Text, DragDropEffects.Link);
}

private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Url.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

The `DoDragDrop` method gets executed correctly, but I never see the `MessageBox` appearing when dropping the string from the `TextBox` over the `WebControl`. Since the `WebControl` doesn't offer the usual drag & drop events I'm lost.

What do I have to do to make the url drop to the `WebBrowser` control work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following approach to initiate `FileDrop` dragging:

```
DataObject dObj = new DataObject();
var paths = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();
paths.Add(textBox1.Text);
dObj.SetFileDropList(paths);
textBox1.DoDragDrop(dObj, DragDropEffects.Link);
```